# trying to insert pandas with alchemy got error fetchall

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert pandas into SQL Server table with chunksize but I got this error.

The error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\neyma\PycharmProjects\pythonProject23\main.py", line 95, in 
> for row in conn.fetchall():
> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

and this my code

```
 connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
    )
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
    conn = engine.connect().execution_options(
        stream_results=True)
    
    
    
    with open("ss.xml") as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
    data = []
    
            'DSName': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="DSName"]'))) else None,
            'DSType': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="DSType"]'))) else None,
            'ObjectDN': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="ObjectDN"]'))) else None,
            'ObjectGUID': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="ObjectGUID"]'))) else None,
            'ObjectClass': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="ObjectClass"]'))) else None,
            'AttributeLDAPDisplayName': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="AttributeLDAPDisplayName"]'))) else None,
            'AttributeSyntaxOID': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="AttributeSyntaxOID"]'))) else None,
            'AttributeValue': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="AttributeValue"]'))) else None,
            'OperationType': e.text if (e := Event.select_one(('Data[Name="OperationType"]'))) else None,
    
    
        })
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data);
    engine.execute('''
    
                                CREATE TABLE try(
                                    DSName nvarchar(max),
                                    DSType nvarchar(max),
                                    ObjectDN nvarchar(max),
                                    ObjectGUID nvarchar (max),
                                    AttributeLDAPDisplayName nvarchar(max),
                                    AttributeSyntaxOID nvarchar(max),
                                    AttributeValue nvarchar(max),
                                    OperationType nvarchar(max),
                                    )
                                       ''')
    df.to_sql('try', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False,chunksize=100)
    engine.execute('''  
    SELECT * FROM test
              ''')
    
    for row in conn.fetchall():
        print (row)
```

Comment: Did the answer below resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake seems to be in the use of `fetchall()`. As the error tells you the `conn` object does not support `fetchall()` and that's true. It is the query results that contain/support this function as shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Change the last loop to

```
result = engine.execute('''  
SELECT * FROM test
          ''')

 for row in result.fetchall():
        print (row)
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
for row in engine.execute('''SELECT * FROM test''').fetchall()
    print(row)
```

**Edit:**
A version that will work with versions >2.0 of SQLAlchemy is

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM test").all()
```

Thanks to [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) for highlighting this in the comments and some more details for the SQLAlchemy part can be found [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=engine%20execute#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute).

Comment: "RemovedIn20Warning: The Engine.execute() method is considered legacy as of the 1.x series of SQLAlchemy and will be removed in 2.0. All statement execution in SQLAlchemy 2.0 is performed by the Connection.execute() method of Connection, or in the ORM by the Session.execute() method of Session. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)" - A more future-proof answer would use `with engine.begin() as conn:` followed by `result = conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM test").all()`